# Generically convert IQueryable list to a list of dto objects

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, asp.net-web-api

**Background**

I have an extension method that converts a list of IQueryable<> to an IEnumerable<>:

```
public static IEnumerable<PersonDto> ToDtoList(
    this IQueryable<Person> source)
{
    var result = new List<PersonDto>();

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        result.Add(item.ToDto());
    }

    return result;
}
```

The `item.ToDto` extension does this:

```
public static PersonDto ToDto(this Person source)
{
    if (source == null)
        return null;

    return new PersonDto
    {
        PersonId = source.personId,
        Firstname = source.firstname,
        Lastname = source.lastname,
        DateOfBirth = source.dateOfBirth,
        CreateDate = source.createDate,
        ModifyDate = source.modifyDate,
    };
}
```

**The question**

Is there a way to configure the following so that `item.ToDto()` works?

```
public static IEnumerable<T2> ToDtoList<T, T2>(this IQueryable<T> source)
{
    var result = new List<T2>();

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        result.Add(item.ToDto());
    }

    return result;
}
```

As is, it doesn't work because `.ToDto` is an unresolvable symbol for `item`.

Comment: You can create custom interface like `IToDto`. And then inherit all `DTO` classes from that. And add constraint to your generic method as ` where T : IToDto`

Comment: Is that `IToDto` Interface something you can leave blank than?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (as you may know) is how to "generically" map a `T` to a `T2`?

You can either use a tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) that you can configure to map generically between any two types, or you can add a parameter for a mapping function:

```
public static IEnumerable<T2> ToDtoList<T, T2>(this IQueryable<T> source, Func<T, T2> map)
{
    var result = source.AsEnumerable()  // to avoid projecting the map into the query
                       .Select(s => map(s));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The `Automapper` option would be ideal, but it's not realistic given the (huge) historical differences between DL and BL. Using the proposed map function means an otherwise very easy to use mapping tool becomes more complex, so I'm not going to opt for that. That said, you provided me with a very workable answer to my question, so thanks!